# How to add the description box at the bottom of the svg map for every cities you mouse hover?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I want to put the description for every cities at the bottom of the map. By which for every cities the details could be seen at the same place and I have to add many information for every cities that's why I want to put the description box at the bottom of the map. Is there any way that I can do this task. I have tried many ways but it's not coming up at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Sample problem related to my issue https://codepen.io/brianplaza/pen/DfKsx/

Comment: Can you put some code so we can help you?

Comment: @javimovi This is the sample code related to my problem https://codepen.io/brianplaza/pen/DfKsx/

Comment: It does not appear anywhere because it has a display: none

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've reduced a lot your code  for the sake of clarity. All I've done was removing parts of your code you'll find commented out. Also, please don't use `width="959px" height="593px" viewBox="none"` use `viewBox="0 0 959 593"`, This will make your SVG as large as the "container" - the `body` in this case.

```js
$description = $(".description");

  $('.enabled').hover(function() {
    
    $(this).attr("class", "enabled heyo");
    $description.addClass('active');
    $description.html($(this).attr('id'));
  }, function() {
    $description.removeClass('active');
  });
/*
$(document).on('mousemove', function(e){
  
  $description.css({
    left:  e.pageX,
    top:   e.pageY - 70
  });
  
});*/
```

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
}

svg {
  /*max-width: 100% !important;*/
  width:100vh;
  /*height: auto;*/
  display: block;
  border:1px solid;
}

.heyo:hover {
  fill: #CC2929;
  -moz-transition: 0.3s;
  -o-transition: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.enabled {
  fill: #21669E;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.description {
  /*pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;*/
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  background: white;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  z-index: 5;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: #21669e;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #eee;
  /*-moz-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);*/
  display: none;
}
.description.active {
  display: block;
}
.description:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 100%;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  margin-left: -10px;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-top: 10px solid white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" viewBox="0 400 959 193" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" xml:space="preserve" >

<path id="Alaska" class="enabled" fill="#21669E" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="0.75" d="M158.1,453.7l-0.3,85.4l1.6,1l3.1,0.2l1.5-1.1h2.6l0.2,2.9
 l7,6.8l0.5,2.6l3.4-1.9l0.6-0.2l0.3-3.1l1.5-1.6l1.1-0.2l1.9-1.5l3.1,2.1l0.6,2.9l1.9,1.1l1.1,2.4l3.9,1.8l3.4,6l2.7,3.9l2.3,2.7
 l1.5,3.7l5,1.8l5.2,2.1l1,4.4l0.5,3.1l-1,3.4l-1.8,2.3l-1.6-0.8l-1.5-3.1l-2.7-1.5l-1.8-1.1l-0.8,0.8l1.5,2.7l0.2,3.7l-1.1,0.5
 l-1.9-1.9l-2.1-1.3l0.5,1.6l1.3,1.8l-0.8,0.8c0,0-0.8-0.3-1.3-1c-0.5-0.6-2.1-3.4-2.1-3.4l-1-2.3c0,0-0.3,1.3-1,1
 c-0.6-0.3-1.3-1.5-1.3-1.5l1.8-1.9l-1.5-1.5v-5h-0.8l-0.8,3.4l-1.1,0.5l-1-3.7l-0.6-3.7l-0.8-0.5l0.3,5.7v1.1l-1.5-1.3l-3.6-6
 l-2.1-0.5l-0.6-3.7l-1.6-2.9l-1.6-1.1v-2.3l2.1-1.3l-0.5-0.3l-2.6,0.6l-3.4-2.4l-2.6-2.9l-4.8-2.6l-4-2.6l1.3-3.2v-1.6l-1.8,1.6
 l-2.9,1.1l-3.7-1.1l-5.7-2.4h-5.5l-0.6,0.5l-6.5-3.9l-2.1-0.3l-2.7-5.8l-3.6,0.3l-3.6,1.5l0.5,4.5l1.1-2.9l1,0.3l-1.5,4.4l3.2-2.7
 l0.6,1.6l-3.9,4.4l-1.3-0.3l-0.5-1.9l-1.3-0.8l-1.3,1.1l-2.7-1.8l-3.1,2.1l-1.8,2.1l-3.4,2.1l-4.7-0.2l-0.5-2.1l3.7-0.6v-1.3
 l-2.3-0.6l1-2.4l2.3-3.9v-1.8l0.2-0.8l4.4-2.3l1,1.3h2.7l-1.3-2.6l-3.7-0.3l-5,2.7l-2.4,3.4l-1.8,2.6l-1.1,2.3l-4.2,1.5l-3.1,2.6
 l-0.3,1.6l2.3,1l0.8,2.1l-2.7,3.2l-6.5,4.2l-7.8,4.2l-2.1,1.1l-5.3,1.1l-5.3,2.3l1.8,1.3l-1.5,1.5l-0.5,1.1l-2.7-1l-3.2,0.2
 l-0.8,2.3h-1l0.3-2.4l-3.6,1.3l-2.9,1l-3.4-1.3l-2.9,1.9h-3.2l-2.1,1.3l-1.6,0.8l-2.1-0.3l-2.6-1.1l-2.3,0.6l-1,1l-1.6-1.1v-1.9
 l3.1-1.3l6.3,0.6l4.4-1.6l2.1-2.1l2.9-0.6l1.8-0.8l2.7,0.2l1.6,1.3l1-0.3l2.3-2.7l3.1-1l3.4-0.6l1.3-0.3l0.6,0.5h0.8l1.3-3.7l4-1.5
 l1.9-3.7l2.3-4.5l1.6-1.5l0.3-2.6l-1.6,1.3l-3.4,0.6l-0.6-2.4l-1.3-0.3l-1,1l-0.2,2.9l-1.5-0.2l-1.5-5.8l-1.3,1.3l-1.1-0.5l-0.3-1.9
 l-4,0.2l-2.1,1.1l-2.6-0.3l1.5-1.5l0.5-2.6l-0.6-1.9l1.5-1l1.3-0.2l-0.6-1.8v-4.4l-1-1l-0.8,1.5h-6.1l-1.5-1.3l-0.6-3.9l-2.1-3.6v-1
 l2.1-0.8L53,514l1.1-1.1l-0.8-0.5l-1.3,0.5l-1.1-2.7l1-5l4.5-3.2l2.6-1.6l1.9-3.7l2.7-1.3l2.6,1.1l0.3,2.4l2.4-0.3l3.2-2.4l1.6,0.6
 l1,0.6h1.6l2.3-1.3l0.8-4.4c0,0,0.3-2.9,1-3.4c0.6-0.5,1-1,1-1l-1.1-1.9l-2.6,0.8l-3.2,0.8l-1.9-0.5l-3.6-1.8l-5-0.2l-3.6-3.7
 l0.5-3.9l0.6-2.4l-2.1-1.8l-1.9-3.7l0.5-0.8l6.8-0.5h2.1l1,1h0.6l-0.2-1.6l3.9-0.6l2.6,0.3l1.5,1.1l-1.5,2.1l-0.5,1.5l2.7,1.6l5,1.8
 l1.8-1l-2.3-4.4l-1-3.2l1-0.8l-3.4-1.9l-0.5-1.1l0.5-1.6l-0.8-3.9l-2.9-4.7l-2.4-4.2l2.9-1.9h3.2l1.8,0.6l4.2-0.2l3.7-3.6l1.1-3.1
 l3.7-2.4l1.6,1l2.7-0.6l3.7-2.1l1.1-0.2l1,0.8l4.5-0.2l2.7-3.1h1.1l3.6,2.4l1.9,2.1l-0.5,1.1l0.6,1.1l1.6-1.6l3.9,0.3l0.3,3.7
 l1.9,1.5l7.1,0.6l6.3,4.2l1.5-1l5.2,2.6l2.1-0.6l1.9-0.8l4.8,1.9L158.1,453.7L158.1,453.7z M43,482.6l2.1,5.3l-0.2,1l-2.9-0.3
 l-1.8-4l-1.8-1.5H36l-0.2-2.6l1.8-2.4l1.1,2.4l1.5,1.5L43,482.6z M40.4,516.1l3.7,0.8l3.7,1l0.8,1l-1.6,3.7l-3.1-0.2l-3.4-3.6
 L40.4,516.1z M19.7,502l1.1,2.6l1.1,1.6l-1.1,0.8l-2.1-3.1V502H19.7L19.7,502z M6,575.1l3.4-2.3l3.4-1l2.6,0.3l0.5,1.6l1.9,0.5
 l1.9-1.9l-0.3-1.6l2.7-0.6l2.9,2.6l-1.1,1.8l-4.4,1.1l-2.7-0.5l-3.7-1.1l-4.4,1.5l-1.6,0.3L6,575.1L6,575.1z M54.9,570.6l1.6,1.9
 l2.1-1.6l-1.5-1.3L54.9,570.6z M57.8,573.6l1.1-2.3l2.1,0.3l-0.8,1.9H57.8z M81.4,571.7l1.5,1.8l1-1.1l-0.8-1.9L81.4,571.7z
  M90.2,559.2l1.1,5.8l2.9,0.8l5-2.9l4.4-2.6l-1.6-2.4l0.5-2.4l-2.1,1.3l-2.9-0.8l1.6-1.1l1.9,0.8l3.9-1.8l0.5-1.5l-2.4-0.8l0.8-1.9
 l-2.7,1.9l-4.7,3.6l-4.9,2.9L90.2,559.2L90.2,559.2z M132.5,539.4l2.4-1.5l-1-1.8l-1.8,1L132.5,539.4z"/>

</svg>

<div class="description"></div>
```

Also: this is a fork of your pen: https://codepen.io/enxaneta/pen/87dc4facb04e657fea5c9a5eb7b2ea3c/